# How do I hit these Riddler switches that are blocked when I step on a pressure plate?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I can't find a solution to this enigma.

When I am over the button, grates rise which keep me from shooting the 3 question marks:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set explosive gel on the question marks beforehand, then go stand on the button, zoom in and use the remote detonator to detonate the gels in the correct sequence.

Comment: I did, but they need to explode in an exact sequence

Comment: Hmm never heard of this mode :D i will find

Comment: I have all upgrade but still I have only the central mouse button to explode them all :(

Comment: AHHH okok I need to zoom in!!!

Comment: please take a look at this :D http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44996/how-to-get-this-trophee-blocked-by-a-destructible-wall