# How to get this trophée blocked by a destructible wall?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I can't destroy this destructible wall placed on top of me.

This is about at the start of wonder city

Comment: You might want to re-upload to stack.imgur the image currently hosted on imageshack, as it's been transformed into an ad. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to glide off the opposite side, and use the grapnel boost to grapple to the top edge and crash into the destructible roof to break it. You can then use the Batclaw to pick up the trophy as normal.

Comment: Oh my.. I am having hard time to translate your answer. Especially the grapnel boost?

Comment: AHHH okkkkk I got it. Wow that was hard

Comment: Grapnel Boost: Double-tap Space after a grapnel (F). You have to complete the first set of AR challenges to unlock it.